# Finding the BindingSource index of a particular Item

Tags: c#, database

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to set the Position of a BindingSource, to point to a Row who's primary key is some precomputed value.

Example:

I have a DB table that stores Classes. A DataGridView is bound to a binding source for that table. The user selects a Class Name from a combo-box, the system finds which row has the selected Class Name and the binding source position is set to the index of that row in the binding source.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
BindingSource.Position = BindingSource.Find("CLASS_NAME", value);
```

where CLASS_NAME is the name of the column that stores the class name in db, and value is the value you are searching for.
Hope that helps